# ASP.Net unhandled exception handler to manipulate response

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.net website that needs to send back an error response in the httpcontext when an unhandled exception occurs. I cannot redirect to another page because the consumer will be hitting my site only for logon purposes and will not see any page other than the response.

I thought of using `System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandler`, but my site runs out of .Net 3.5 framework and am not able to use it.

Can someone give me an idea of what I can do, I need a common httpmodule that traps all the exception and then sends a httpresponse with an error message in the following format.

```
<response>
  <error>
    <code>101</code>
    <description>error from the exception</description>
  </error>
</response>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do the following in Global.asax code (converted from VB)

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();

    Logging.LogError(exception);
    //Get a HTML file stored in resources which contains my error text and some tokens to replace.
    dynamic html = My.Resources.ErrorText;
    html = html.Replace("{Title}", Server.HtmlEncode(My.Application.Info.Title));
    html = html.Replace("{Product}", Server.HtmlEncode(My.Application.Info.ProductName));
    html = html.Replace("{Version}", Server.HtmlEncode(My.Application.Info.Version.ToString));

    //Build my exception message looping though all the inner exceptions
    dynamic errorDetails = exception.Message + Constants.vbNewLine + exception.StackTrace;

    while (exception.InnerException != null) {
        exception = exception.InnerException;
        errorDetails += Constants.vbNewLine + Constants.vbNewLine + "Inner Exception: " + Constants.vbNewLine + exception.Message + Constants.vbNewLine + exception.StackTrace;
    }

    //Replace the {ErrorDetails} tag with my error text
    html = html.Replace("{ErrorDetails}", Server.HtmlEncode(errorDetails).Replace(Constants.vbNewLine, "<br/>"));

    //Replace the logo tag
    using (IO.MemoryStream ms = new IO.MemoryStream()) {
        using (img == My.Resources.Logo) {
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            dynamic logoBytes = ms.ToArray;
            html = html.Replace("{Logo}", "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(logoBytes, 0, logoBytes.Length));
        }
    }

    //Replace the response
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(html);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

It should be possible to add a event handler to the HttpApplication.Error event in the init of a httpmodule to do the same. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication_events(v=vs.110).aspx which is passed to the Init method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is it possible for doing it in an httpmodule so I can keep it reusable?

Comment: Looks like it should be possible to add a event handler to the HttpApplication.Error event in the init of a httpmodule. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication_events(v=vs.110).aspx  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule(v=vs.110).aspx